# material design xaml different themes / color palette for different windows / controls

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

WPF using Material Design Toolkit.

I am trying to find out if it is possible to have different color palettes / themes for windows / user controls, so that each window / u-control has its own color theme.

Comment: define multiple styles with keys and set them to your control based on your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From one of the developers in the material design xaml [gitter chat](https://gitter.im/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit):

> as for changing the colors on different views. Yes. You can actually
>   take the same color resource dictionaries that [you add in the App.xaml](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Getting-Started#configuring-your-appxaml)
>   (you only need the color ones; not all of them) and apply them at
>   whatever level in the XAML makes sense. For example if you wanted to
>   change the primary color to Blue for all controls inside of a Grid you
>   could do something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.